# Why doesn't my new GFCI outlet work?

Tags: gfci

I installed a new gfci identically as the one I removed.  The green light is on, but it isn't working.  I hit the reset button, still nothing.  I hit the test button, but it doesn't budge.  Please help

Comment: Please revise to add more details. A photo would really help. The most common mistake is connecting the load wires to the line terminals, or vice-versa. They're not always in the same position. We can't know without more information.

Comment: Model number of old and new would help

Comment: +1 on the most common issue being connecting to the wrong terminals.

Answer (score 4):

Hook up 2 wires to the LINE terminals only.  Cap off the others.  Plug something into it.  Switch the breaker back on and see if the appliance powers up.  If it doesn't, you got the LINE terminals wrong.  Power back down and Work on that.

Once the unit powers up and acts normally, *then* hook up the other wires.